# Format 2nd child from a list item

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a `ul` item and within it I have 2 more `ul` items. I need to format the 2nd row in the `ul`.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/M345N/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="horizontal">
    <li>First List
    <ul class="ul1">
        <li>first</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
    </ul>
    <li>Second List
    <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.horizontal >li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

ul:nth-child(2) {
    color:RED
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `li:nth-of-type(2)` work?

Comment: You have different selectors in your code, and a different one is used in the fiddle, so make sure you edit the question accordingly :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the selector below..

```
ul > li > ul > li:nth-of-type(2) {
   color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M345N/1/)

Explanation: The above selector means select the `ul` element, than move and and select direct `li` nested under `ul`, than move ahead and select direct `ul` nested under `li` and than at the end, we select the 2nd `li` nested under the second level `ul`.

Also, only `li` elements can be nested inside the `ul` as the direct childrens, you can also use `nth-child` too

Answer (score 0):

`Mr. Alien` is correct but instead making your CSS very specific, could you not just use a class on the `ul` or even the `li` in question.  This would make your CSS easier to manage/override in the future.

It's important to remember that the browser works from right to left when reading CSS and applying it.

**Example**

```
<ul class="horizontal">
    <li>First List
    <ul class="ul1 nested-list">
        <li>first</li>
        <li class="list-item-red">Second</li>
       <li>Third</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Second List
        <ul class="nested-list">
            <li>first</li>
            <li class="list-item-red">Second</li>
            <li>Third</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

.list-item-red { color: red; }
```

Comment: No, we cannot make that specific and declare the classes if the items are generated dynamically..

Comment: I would argue that was possible, if not at the `li` level then certainly on the  nested `ul`'s

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is not working is because you are selecting the `:nth-child` UL, not the LI. Pseudo selectors (like :nth's) work on your current selector, not its children. This is quite confusing for things like `:first-child` and `:nth-child`, but remember it like this:  `something:is`, like `a:hover`